# Application appears off screen

Tags: notepad

For some reason, notepad.exe starts up off the physical screen in some virtual location. As such I cannot use it. It's in the taskbar so I can kill it. Is there anyway to have it reset its top left corner so I can use it again?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>. Then move it.

Comment: Upon pressing Alt-Space,M -- I'd suggest using/holding down arrow keys to get the window moving first.  Once you see it, you should be able to use your mouse to move the window to where you want it.

Comment: I wasn't able to move it, but `ALT` + `SPACE` opened a menu where I could choose maximize, and that fixed things.

Comment: This hotkey (`Alt+Space`) does not work in Windows 10 anymore. Luckily, Elles's answer still works on Windows 10 :).

Answer (score 12):

If you feel comfortable going through the registry, here's a way to reset Notepad's window position:

1. Close Notepad
2. On the Registry editor, go to:
   `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`
3. Delete `fSaveWindowPositions` and/or
   `iWindowPos*`

Comment: This worked great. Thank you.

Comment: This still works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 8.1, press <kbd>[image] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>**←** (left arrow)</kbd>, and the document will appear on the left half of your screen. 
Then drag the size a bit and it resets the window position.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem.  I didn't try the Regedit method as my work computer is locked down.  I tried the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> method but didn't work.  I tried the right click move on the Task Manager but there is no such move option on my Windows 7 OS in Task Manager.

So to solve the problem I

- launched Notepad,
- opened up Task Manager,
- right clicked on Notepad,
- left clicked Maximize

and it appeared on my screen again. I was then able to

- click on the resize square in the upper right corner of the Notepad window
- resize and
- close Notepad.

I then relaunched Notepad and it appeared on my screen again.

Comment: Life saver. Thanks! Getting tired of these Windows 10 bugs.

Comment: Awesome. The only answer that actually solves the problem instead of giving a workaround you have to use every time you reopen Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to Bruce post but I was having similar issues on Atom (I googled and this thread came up as an answer)
You could also try:
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> then click maximise

Comment: yes a new user is not allowed to comment, with time you can increase your rep by answering questions etc and then you can comment. This is a very old question so you can always just remove your answer instead of having other vote down your answer. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Open a notepad, hover over it in the taskbar. Right click on it then click move, at this point use your arrowkeys to move the window back on screen not the mouse. (If you dont know where the window is keep clicking on the taskbar where the icon is located and it will minimize and maximize, indicating its location off screen).