# How to change notepad default size and position?

Tags: windows-7, notepad

On my Windows 7 PC, notepad opens at the same position and its window has same size each time. In [Application appears off screen](https://superuser.com/questions/281150/application-appears-off-screen) thread Kaze gives the way to reset it by deleting some registry entries:

> Delete `fSaveWindowPositions` and/or `iWindowPos*` on the
>   `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`

However is there a more nifty way to reset (or change) the default size and position of the notepad? Or am I going to clean registry each time I want to change the defaults?

Definitely it isn't difficult to programm this, but I thought Windows should have some built-in way to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have just found the answer in [Make Windows 7 remember window positions and size!](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/8801-make-windows-7-remember-window-positions-size-20.html):

> I got success in getting Windows 7 to remember size and position by
>   right clicking on the top title bar, selecting 'Size' from the menu,
>   and so long as that arrow icon is being used resizing the window using
>   that. Closing the window afterwards then reopening got me my
>   remembered size and positions in IE8, Wordpad, and Notepad.

Indeed it's not very obvious..., at least for me.

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10.