# axcrypt opens off-screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

After switching to Windows 10, I am having trouble with the open-source version of axcrypt (1.7.3156). For some reason, the window to open/decrypt a file appears off-screen. I'm able to type the password blind, but would rather see the window.

I've tried tricks from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/281150/application-appears-off-screen):

- Alt-Space + M (can't seem to move the window on-screen)
- Looking in the registry for a stored position (none of the keys in HKCU/Software/Axantum/Axcrypt seem related to that issue). Same in HKLM.
- Stacking the current windows by right-clicking the task bar (the window doesn't reappear)
- Windows + arrows has no effect on that particular window
- Unlocking the task bar

Since there's no task bar icon, some of the options are not available.

Would someone have other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over three months after asking the question, an idea arose while using AutoHotkey, leading to this solution.

**Automatically Moving the Hidden Window using AutoHotkey**

1. Identify the window class using the [WindowList script](http://www.computoredge.com/AutoHotkey/Free_AutoHotkey_Scripts_and_Apps_for_Learning_and_Generating_Ideas.html#WindowList).
2. Write script that detects the window and moves it.
3. Run script at startup.

Here is the script I wrote. So short!

```
; Moves AxCrypt decryption dialog as soon as it opens

SetTitleMatchMode, 3 ; exact match
Loop 
{ 
   WinWait, ahk_class #32770
   WinMove, ahk_class #32770, , 800, 500 
   WinWaitClose, ahk_class #32770 ; if the window is still there, no need to loop
}
```

Now I love AutoHotkey even more.

If you have other applications opening windows with `ahk_class #32770`, you may want to inject a condition such as `if(WinActive("ahk_exe AXCrypt.exe"))`

**How it Works**

- [`SetTitleMatchMode`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) sets the match mode for [`WinTitle`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) to 3, which is the exact mode, ensuring we only match this window.
- [`Loop`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) runs an infinite loop.
- [`WinWait`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) waits for the correct AxCrypt window to be open
- [`WinMove`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) moves the window to new screen coordinates: 800, 500
- [`WinWaitClose`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitClose.htm) waits for the window to close, otherwise we will repeat the loop unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

this is Svante, the author of AxCrypt.

There are issues with offscreen dialogs in Windows 10. It may have to do with the use of external screens with laptops, but I'm not sure. Unfortunately, AxCrypt 1.7 is not really actively developed, I've switched all focus to version 2.

You might want to try that out, it does handle Windows 10 better.

Comment: Thank you for your kind message, Svante. My understanding was that version 2 is not open-source, so I was hoping to find a solution for version 1.7. At the moment it is very workable, just not ideal.

Comment: Version 2 is indeed open source! https://bitbucket.org/axantum/axcrypt-net .